JAVA FileInputStream read slow from cifs if it's opened while the file is being written to from another cifs client
The issue was found in a extract-and-copy operation. A JAVA program on Windows server with CIFS client would extract a zip file from and to a CIFS mount. Then another server with basically the same configuration would copy the extracted file from the CIFS mount to a local drive. We found that if the copy operation is started while the extraction is ongoing, which is to say that the file is being written to, the transfer rate of the copy operation would become extremly slow, like about 1/10 or 1/15 of the speed it should have.
The issue can be reproduced every time the conditions are met. And another confusing thing we found is that while the copy is transfering at low data rate, if another inputstream of that file is opened by that JAVA program, both of the streams would began to transfer at normal rate. By looking at the output file sizes of the copy operations, we found that both inputstream seems to be reading to the same position at the same time since the output file sizes are the same.
We haven't be able to find whether this is caused by apache commons-vfs2 we're using or CIFS itself. And the issue cannot be reproduced if the extraction and copy is done on the same server. Any thought on how to identify the cause?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
